# How to use AWS ECS Service Discovery Endpoint in Java Springboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am new to AWS ECS. I am developing two services in Java Spring Boot, Service 1 and Service 2. I have created two ECS services with one task each, in the same cluster.

I can see that there is a "Service Discovery Endpoint" Service2.local and "Service discovery name" Service2. I can also see SRV and Type A record in Route 53 for Service 2.  I do not know how do I call Service 2 from Service 1. Before I could try from SpringBoot, I tried the following curl command to try to get status from Service2.

```
curl service2.local/status
```

I get the error could not resolve host service2.local . I want to understand how to use the service discovery endpoint or name correctly.

**Edit:**

I have tried to execute the following command, but it returns nothing.

```
dig +short service2.local
```

Comment: Ideally, you should get the response if your app is running. What is the output of `dig +short service2.local` from any your cluster instance?

Comment: dig +short service2.local command returns nothing. I do not see any error message. When I run this command, the control returns to the prompot.

Comment: Please check your hosted zone(.local) and check if there are some records or not.

Comment: Dig you ever figure out how to communicate via HTTP requests between your services?

Answer (score 0):

If

1. you have the entry in your hosted zone

and

2. you can curl using the posted IP inside your hosted zone (so the ports are correct and the security groups work, and the app is up) then:

**Check that your VPC has both DNS hostnames and DNS resolution** otherwise AWS will not resolve the DNS server correctly.  (NB it can take a while for it to come online, go brew a cuppa while you wait)